# Can two class members be used in the same function? (classes and objects) (C++)

Tags: c++, class, object

I am new to programming and I have started with C++. At this point I am experimenting with classes and objects.

My problem is that I am not able to get the correct result in what I want.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Variable
{
public:
    int classAnum;
    int classBnum;
    void sumVar(){
        cout << classAnum + classBnum <<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Variable numA;
    Variable numB;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> numA.classAnum;
    cout << "Enter another number: ";
    cin >> numB.classBnum;
    numA,numB.sumVar();
    return 0;
}
```

The output that I am being given is:

```
Enter a number: (any number)
Enrer another number: (any number)
1955294086
```

I get this output with any number I enter.

But if I use this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Variable
{
public:
    int classAnum;
    int classBnum;
    void sumVar(){
        cout << classAnum + classBnum <<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Variable numA;
    Variable numB;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> numA.classAnum;
    cout << "Enter another number: ";
    cin >> numB.classBnum;
    cout << numA.classAnum + numB.classBnum;
    return 0;
}
```

I get a correct result. Can someone explain me if I am able to use two objects in the same function? And if I can, how should it be?

Comment: This just looks like a mistake: you have a `Variable` class which has two members, but then you make you instances of `Variable`. Remove the second instead of `Variable`, and just have both `cin >>` go into `numA`

Comment: Why do you have classAnum and classBnum class members and then create two separate variables numA and numB?

Comment: What do you expect `numA,numB.sumVar();` to do and why do you expect it?

Comment: I wanted to sum two number that the user has entered. Thank you for your interest. Problem solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing your code, it looks like you want to find the sum of two numbers which are members of your class. you don't need to instantiate 2 objects for that, you can accomplish it by instantiating only one object, and initialize the properties this way:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Variable
{
public:
    int number1;
    int number2;
    void sumVar(){
        cout << number1 + number2 <<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Variable object;

    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> object.number1;
    cout << "Enter another number: ";
    cin >> object.number2;
    object.sumVar();

    return 0;
}
```

This way you can easily sum  up members of your class.

in the future, if you want to add two objects of your own classes, you may need to use operator overloading concept that you can find on several tutorial online.

Good Luck !

Comment: So I can use the objects I have made without refering to the class?

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to input two numbers into `Variable` class instance and then call the function `sumVar()` to print the sum of the two numbers, you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Variable
{
public:
    int classAnum;
    int classBnum;
    void sumVar(){
        cout << classAnum + classBnum <<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Variable num;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> num.classAnum;
    cout << "Enter another number: ";
    cin >> num.classBnum;
    num.sumVar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that? Please explain.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you wanted to see how to have multiple members in a class and how to use those members in a class function.

Comment: Explain in the Answer, please. It is more useful to future Askers.